# Visual Studio Code rendering delay?

Tags: performance, editor, visual-studio-code

I've just tried out Visual Studio Code for the first time. The text editor I normally use for small Python hacks and the like is Notepad++, because it's snappy and gets the work done. My immediate reaction to Code, apart from having many great functions, is that the rendering seems magnitudes slower than Notepad++.

Is there a setting that deliberately causes a delay between a keypress and a render update? I realize Code is built on top of a browser, but that in itself shouldn't be a bottleneck right? CPU usage is low, could this be some CPU-to-GPU bandwidth problem? If seems insane that 2016 it should take >.1 seconds to render screen full of text. Especially as I have a pretty powerful machine.

#### Experiment

I don't know how to get hard numbers, but a simple experiment clearly shows the low rendering performance of Code. Open a Python file with 20k+ lines (or copy-paste until you get there). Maximize the window and place the cursor at the top of the file and press and hold the PageDown key. Notepad++ renders att full frame rate on my HD screen, Code stutters and you get the feeling it's not running att full frame rate. Also try pressing the PageUp/PageDown once per editor. In Notepad++ it's hard to release the key before the rendering is already completed, while Code *always* finishes rendering some time after you've released the key.

#### Update: hard data

Key-press timing data reveals that a adding/deleting a single character is [47% slower](https://thume.ca/2020/05/20/making-a-latency-tester/) in VSCode than in Sublime on a Mac. And whole page updates are much, much worse (at least on Windows).

Comment: I have used Visual Studio for some projects for many years and the screen rendering delay is a huge distraction. I have never found a fix and I found your post via google because I just started a new project and yet again this issue is getting under my skin. Some people can't see it but there is a noticiable delay when moving the cursor arround one character at a time. The delay is not only keyboard lag but highlting lag as well.  If you watch carefully you can move the cursor one space, delay, then see highliting change on screen. The net result is the editor feels sluggish all day long.

Comment: @BrianEnsink: Hear hear! I suspect this is due to some type of optimization or other. It's probably as you say, that most users (and VSC developers) doesn't notice it.

Comment: I've also noticed VS Code has very slow rendering when trying to run it via X server. Due to requirements of employer and projects, I have to develop code in a virtual machine running Ubuntu on a Windows 10 host machine. For a more seamless experience, I like to run an X server on Win 10 and run my Linux GUI programs in windows; most text editors such as Gedit and Geany are still very fast and usable but VS Code is painful. Annoying because otherwise VS Code has many useful features without being bloated.